# When a function is passed as an argument, how are parameters passed to that function?

Tags: javascript, html

In code for an HTML page, a button "Try It" causes a google map to appear in a window, centered on the user's location. It does this by calling getLocation(), which in turn calls showPosition(). However, there is no parameter passed in the line

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
```

And showPosition is defined to accept a parameter. The code you see below indicates this. While experimenting, I modified the code by removing the parameter from the definition, but the map ceased to appear. The code below is the version that *shows* the map.

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}


function showPosition(position) {
    var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
    zoom:13,
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>
```

I'm very curious after seeing this. How is the parameter "position" accessed in showPosition() when it is not passed into it? If anyone can explain the reason I would be very grateful.

Comment: It's a callback function. There's more information on the method `getCurrentPosition` here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)  and since it's JavaScript, reading up on callbacks is essential

Comment: The example in your question can be considered a light introduction to "point-free" style. Here are more in-depth examples. Enjoy! http://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/pointfree-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentPosition` is using `showPosition` a callback function. That means it calls it and provides the `position` as the first argument. If you were to supply arguments to `showPosition`, `getCurrentPosition` would be using the return value.

Answer (score 0):

ShowPosition hasn't been called in the code you've posted. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);` is passing the *function* showPosition to getCurrentPosition. getCurrentPosition may call showPosition in its code or pass it along to another function

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [`geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), you'll see that the first parameter is a success callback function. This means that `getCurrentPosition` executes the function to pass to it when the user's position is determined. It then passes the position value to that callback function - in this example, `showPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

`getCurrentPosition`'s argument is a function. In Javascipt functions are 'first-class citizens' and can be passed as arguments like this.

The documentation states that the way `getCurrentPosition` works is that it accepts a callback parameter `success`(in this case, it is the function `showPosition`), and will then call that function with a Position parameter when it has the location. That's how `showPosition` gets its argument.

This is a very common pattern in Javascript for dealing with asynchronous functions. Because `getCurrentPosition` can take some time to execute, instead of calling it and waiting for the return value to be ready, you pass it functions. It will then call those functions with the result when it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `navigator.gelocation.getCurrentPosition` is the function `showPosition`. It's not actually calling `showPosition` at this point, just sending it as a parameter. The reason why you are confused is because you can't see the definition for `getCurrentPosition`, which could probably look something like this:

```
function getCurrentPosition(callbackFunction) {
    var position = {};
    callbackFunction(position)
}
```

Of course I don't actually know what currentPosition looks like, I'm just using it to demonstrate how `showPosition` can receive an argument from it.